# React context api returning undefined when setting the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I've recently started learning react and i'm using the context api to store my global state.

Here in **MyProvider.js** file i define my provider and its simply stores 2 arrays of json obj

```
import {MyContext} from "./MyContext";
import React, {useState} from "react";

export const MyProvider = (props) => {
    const intialState = {
        featuredListings: [],
        setFeaturedListings: (val) => setState({...state, featuredListings: val}),
        featuredVendors: [],
        setFeaturedVendors: (val) => setState({...state, featuredVendors: val})
    }

    const [state, setState] = useState(intialState)

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={state}
        >
            {props.children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

I'm wrapping all my components in my **App.js** in the Provider by doing this , side not using ReachRouter to handle routing,

```
<MyProvider>
    <div className="content">
        <Header/>
        <Router>
            <Home path="/"/>
        </Router>
    </div>
    <Footer />
</MyProvider>
```

In my **Home.js** file I make a network call in the useEffect hook which successfully returns the json which i expect and with that json response i update the state of the context so that it can be visible globally.

My code for that is

```
export const Home = () => {
    let state = useContext(MyContext)

    async function apiCalls() {
        const featuredVendors = await getFeaturedVendors()
        console.log("featuredVendors - ", featuredVendors) // the correct response is returned
        state.setFeaturedVendors(featuredVendors)

        const featuredListings = await getFeaturedListing()
        console.log("featuredListings - ", featuredListings) // the correct response is returned
        state.setFeaturedListings(featuredListings)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        apiCalls()
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(state.featuredVendors)}  // empty array
            {console.log(state.featuredListings)} // contains correct values
        </div>
    )
}
```

]

To remove any ambiguity my Context is created in a separate file which is Called **MyContext.js**
and I create the Context like so

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext()
```

Why is the *state.featuredVendors* not updating when I set it?

Also another strange thing i noticed is if I rearrange the orders of the calls , i.e call the 
*getFeaturedListing* first followed by the *getFeaturedVendors* then my state only updates for featuredVendors and featuredListings will be an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `useState` the initialValue is only set once. When your MyProvider is first mounted, the state is initialised with your `setFeaturedListings` and `setFeaturedVendors` methods but these are not updated whenever the value of `state` changes.  Therefore the value of  `state` when you spread the values will always be its initial value.

`setState` can also be called with a function that always receives the current value as an argument, so you could rewrite these methods to spread that value like so:

```
    const intialState = {
        featuredListings: [],
        setFeaturedListings: (val) => setState(state => ({...state, featuredListings: val})),
        featuredVendors: [],
        setFeaturedVendors: (val) => setState(state => ({...state, featuredVendors: val}))
    }
```

Or, alternatively, you could move these functions outside of your state altogether.

```
export const MyProvider = (props) => {
  const intialState = {
      featuredListings: [],
      featuredVendors: [],
  }
  const [state, setState] = useState(intialState)
  return (
      <MyContext.Provider
          value={{
            ...state,
            setFeaturedListings: (val) => setState({...state, featuredListings: val}),
            setFeaturedVendors: (val) => setState({...state, featuredVendors: val})
          }}
      >
          {props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```